# Sitemap contains urls which are blocked by robots.txt. this error is showing in google webmaster console

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting below mentioned error in my Google webmaster console.

> The sitemap contains URLs which are blocked by robots.txt.

My store link is `www.pathankotmandi.com`. sitemap file name is sitemap.

Could you please help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Hi. Am experiencing the same issue with Google search console in that custom site maps are being flagged as "the sitemap contains urls which are blocked by robots.txt".  However ALL the individual URLs can be pulled into "fetch as google", have replaced the actual robots.txt file with "User-agent: * Allow: /"  and GSC still reports the issue.  I am a long-term web dev and this is driving me crazy.  This only happens on this one word press site though, but this is the only site of mine currently using apache2.4

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw your robots.txt file and you do not have specific paths dissallowed. 
But, you should try inserting this into robots.txt:

User-agent: *
Allow: /

Answer (score 0):

In your file structure you evidently, as the error suggest, have files named robot.txt.  These files tell webcrawlers not crawl certain areas of your site.  Respectable search engines respect these and will not crawl the directories that the text files are in.  If you want certain areas of your site crawled remove or change the robot.txt file to do what you need it to do.

Here is some reading to better inform you:

http://www.robotstxt.org/